# how to set a title and fullscreen flag for cocos2dx window

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, game-development

I've started to gaming with cocos2dx but I've 2 crucial and important problems:

1. How to set a title for the window
2. How to set a full screen flag for the window

I've read the CCApplication and CCDirector files and I've also tried to make some changes in those files but my problem hasn't been solved
I really appreciate if you can help me with those problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Setting title bar we can do it using windows handle

```
HWND _handle= eglView->getHWnd();
SetWindowText(_handle, "Title");
```

Comment: thank u very much for this useful answer,so is there a way for set the window fulscreen??